# 'while' loop with characters converted to ASCII code (intermediate level)

Tags: python, while-loop, ord

I'm working through examples where I have to convert 'for' loops into 'while' loops, and this one has me stumped. The problem for me is that 'for' loops are perfectly designed to iterate over each character in a string, and then that character can be easily cast as 'ord' to get its ASCII code. But converting this to a 'while' loop is giving me issues when I try to retrieve the 'ord' part of this. I've attempted it using split() and trying to find each letter using an index, but it isn't working so far.

Please note that the code itself is just rubbish code that doesn't produce anything useful - it is purely just for practising 'while' loops. Thanks!

Supplied problem to be converted into a 'while' loop:

```
def convert(string):
    """take string and return an int that is the unicode version"""
    num = 0
    for char in string:
        if ord(char) > 20:
            num = ord(char) - 10
        else:
            num = ord(char) * 2
    return num
print(convert('Test this string'))
```

My attempt at the 'while' loop version:

```
def convert(string):
    """take string and return an int that is the unicode version"""
    char_value = string.split()
    num = 0
    char_index = 0
    while char_index < len(string):
        if ord(char_value[char_index]) > 20:
            num = char_value - 10
        else:
            num = char_value * 2
        char_index += 1    
    return num
print(convert('Test this string'))
```

EDIT: here is the working solution as adapted after NPE's suggestion (just in case beginners want to see the full solution):

```
def convert(string):
    """take string and return an int that is the unicode version"""
    num = 0
    char_index = 0
    while char_index < len(string):
        char = string[char_index]
        if ord(char) > 20:
            num = ord(char) - 10
        else:
            num = ord(char) * 2
        char_index += 1    
    return num
print(convert('Test this string'))
```

Comment: When you say "giving me issues", what kind of issues exactly? (I.e. what are you expect and what happens instead?)

Comment: "TypeError: ord() expected a character." I can see it doesn't like the fact that an index is int when it wants a char, but I have no idea how to write the while loop to do what a for loop would do here.

Comment: Although there is already an answer below, I'd want to know why exactly you unnecessarily added the `split()`. Did you know that strings can be indexed in Python?

Comment: user202729 - the previous example in the book was very similar and they'd used split(), so I was following along but got stuck at the ord part. These examples aren't to teach the best approach - they're designed to force readers to try out new things in a way I wouldn't normally do it (since I'd use a for loop). As stated, the code is rubbish, it is just an exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `split`. You can index into the string directly with a character index.

A straightforward way to rewrite the `for` as a `while` is shown below:

```
    char_index = 0
    while char_index < len(string):
        char = string[char_index]
        ...
        char_index += 1
```

(The `...` part can be exactly as the body of the `for` loop.)

Comment: Right - I get what you mean. I'd initially tried something similar but got "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' ". So I attempted it the way I'd pasted above, but I've tried a combo of your char line and wrapping it with ord(char) for the rest of it and it works! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose a more elegant and even more equivalent way to write that loop:

```
def convert(string):
    """take string and return an int that is for sure not any kind of Unicode version, whatever that's supposed to be"""
    it = iter(string)
    while True:
        char = next(it, None)
        if char is None:
            break
        if ord(char) > 20:
            num = ord(char) - 10
        else:
            num = ord(char) * 2
    return num
print(convert('Test this string'))
```

Why is the iterator approach more elegant, you may ask. A few simple reasons:

- This works with any sequence, even one that is not indexable.
- You don't have to compute the sequence's length in advance why may require loading it into memory first.
- You could use this with a sequence who's length is infinite (this particular algorithm would loop endlessly then) or one who's length is unknown (think user input).

Comment: It's an excellent solution. This particular exercise wanted the reader to 'mirror' the for loop to compare them like for like (hence my clumsy solution), but your solution reminds me that I need to read up on iterators as I've never used them.